# How to getText from EditText that i created from a JavaClass

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

im new in Android Studio and I'm trying to getText from a EditText that i created from a java class and not visually in the xml. The main idea of the project is try to do a sudoku so what i have:

- 9x9 Table
- Array with 81 numbers
- Some squares of the table have a EditText and others TextViews (like a sudoku)

> But the problem is I dont know how to do a getText from the EditText because 
>   they are not created in a normal way so i cant do "r.id.edittext_1" for 
>   example.

There is another way to getText?

My Files:

**tabla.java** (Where I create the table and all the EditText and TextView)

```
public class Tabla{
// Variables de la clase

private TableLayout tabla;          // Layout donde se pintará la tabla
private ArrayList<TableRow> filas;  // Array de las filas de la tabla
private Activity actividad;
private Resources rs;
private int FILAS, COLUMNAS;        // Filas y columnas de nuestra tabla

/**
 * Constructor de la tabla
 * @param actividad Actividad donde va a estar la tabla
 * @param tabla TableLayout donde se pintará la tabla
 */
public Tabla(Activity actividad, TableLayout tabla)
{
    this.actividad = actividad;
    this.tabla = tabla;
    rs = this.actividad.getResources();
    FILAS = COLUMNAS = 0;
    filas = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
}

/**
 * Añade la cabecera a la tabla
 * @param recursocabecera Recurso (array) donde se encuentra la cabecera de la tabla
 */
public void agregarCabecera(int recursocabecera)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

    String[] arraycabecera = rs.getStringArray(recursocabecera);
    COLUMNAS = arraycabecera.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < arraycabecera.length; i++)
    {
        TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
        layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(arraycabecera[i]), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        texto.setText(arraycabecera[i]);
        texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
        //texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);
        texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);

        fila.addView(texto);
    }

    tabla.addView(fila);
    filas.add(fila);

    FILAS++;
}

/**
 * Agrega una fila a la tabla
 * @param elementos Elementos de la fila
 */
public void agregarFilaTabla(ArrayList<Integer> elementos)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
    fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

    for(int i = 0; i< elementos.size(); i++)
    {
        //Log.v("RESULTADO","X:"+String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
        if(elementos.get(i) == 0){
            EditText texto = new EditText(actividad); //FUNCION PARA PODER EDITAR
            //texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i))); //FUNCION PARA ESCRIBIR NUMERO ARRAY
            //texto.getText().clear(); //FUNCION PARA BORRAR EL TEXTO
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //FUNCION PARA ALINEAR
            texto.setInputType(2); //FUNCION PARA QUE SE PUEDA EDITAR CON NUMEROS SOLO
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_editables); //FUNCION PARA CARGAR EL COLOR DEL TEXTO
            texto.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)}); //FUNCION PARA LIMITAR LA CANTIDAD DE TEXTO
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
            fila.addView(texto);
        }else{
            TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
            texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            //texto.setInputType(0); //FUNCION PARA QUE NO SE PUEDA EDITAR, SOLO APLICAR A EDITTEXT
            texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda);
            texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);
            layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
            fila.addView(texto);
        }

    }

    tabla.addView(fila);
    filas.add(fila);

    FILAS++;
}

/**
 * Elimina una fila de la tabla
 * @param indicefilaeliminar Indice de la fila a eliminar
 */
public void eliminarFila(int indicefilaeliminar)
{
    if( indicefilaeliminar > 0 && indicefilaeliminar < FILAS )
    {
        tabla.removeViewAt(indicefilaeliminar);
        FILAS--;
    }
}

/**
 * Devuelve las filas de la tabla, la cabecera se cuenta como fila
 * @return Filas totales de la tabla
 */
public int getFilas()
{
    return FILAS;
}

/**
 * Devuelve las columnas de la tabla
 * @return Columnas totales de la tabla
 */
public int getColumnas()
{
    return COLUMNAS;
}

/**
 * Devuelve el número de celdas de la tabla, la cabecera se cuenta como fila
 * @return Número de celdas totales de la tabla
 */
public int getCeldasTotales()
{
    return FILAS * COLUMNAS;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el ancho en píxeles de un texto en un String
 * @param texto Texto
 * @return Ancho en píxeles del texto
 */
private int obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(String texto)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    p.setTextSize(50);

    p.getTextBounds(texto, 0, texto.length(), bounds);
    return 100;
}

public int compararSolucion(ArrayList[] bueno , ArrayList[] usuario){
    if(bueno == usuario){
        return 1; //Correcto
    }else{
        return 0; //Malo
    }
}
}
```

**nivel1.java** (Activity class)

```
public class nivel1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nivel1);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<Integer> suddoku = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[] otherList = new Integer[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,4,5,0,0,0,4,2,6,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,6,3,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,6,3,0,9,5,7,2,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,9,0,0,6,3,2,0,8,0,0,1,0,9,0,0,9,5,0,0,8,0,0};
    Integer[] correctList = new Integer[] {7,9,2,6,1,5,3,8,4,5,8,3,7,4,2,6,9,1,1,6,4,3,9,8,5,2,7,9,4,8,2,6,3,7,1,5,2,7,5,4,8,1,9,6,3,6,3,1,9,5,7,2,4,8,8,5,7,1,2,9,4,3,6,3,2,6,8,7,4,1,5,9,4,1,9,5,3,6,8,7,2};
    suddoku.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherList));

    Tabla tabla = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabla));
    tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_tabla);
    int x = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> elementos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(x = x; contador < 9; contador++){
            elementos.add(suddoku.get(x));
            x++;
        }
        contador = 0;

        tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);


    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sudokus, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.resolvertop) {
        return true; //I want when you push this button, you get the text from all the EditText and put in an array, then compare with the complete array.
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return false;
}
}
```

**content_nivel1.xml** (Layout of the activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".nivel1"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_nivel1">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:id="@+id/layoutTexto">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/layoutTabla"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollvertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/scrollhorizontal"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabla"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SOLUTION**

Add this function to the Tabla class

```
 public String returnText(String tag){
    EditText texto = (EditText)tabla.findViewWithTag(tag);

    return texto.getText().toString();
 }
```

And call it from nivel1 class

```
 String texto = tabla.returnText(tag);
```

> **Thank you all for your time and help.**

Comment: when you are creating EditText, setTag with row/col number and add TextWatcher. So when text changes in any of EditText. in afterTextChanged callback with the help of Tag fill your array.

Comment: ok i added the Tag **texto.setTag("EditText"+i);** and now i need to add a TextWatcher, in nivel1.java right?                                                         @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(**what i need to put here?**) {

        
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are creating EditText setTag with row/col.

```
EditText texto = new EditText(actividad);
textTo.setTag(row+col);
```

And when you want getText()

```
EditText texto = (EditText)tabla.findViewWithTag(row+col);
textto.getText()
```

Comment: this is a mistake, you will end up with multiple views with the same tag. For example row 1 column 5 and row 5 column 1 will have the same tag.

Comment: @MidasLefko not if row and col are strings

Comment: row+col is just a hint, we can use anything unique as a tag to identify.

Comment: i created the **EditText texto = (EditText)tabla.findViewWithTag(1);
            texto.getText();** in **nivel1.java** but if i put it inside the OnOptionsItemsSelected() it says "cannot resolve symbol tabla" and if i put them in the **OnCreate()** inside a **Button OnClick()** "tabla is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final" and if i declare it as final "cant resolve method finViewWithTag".

Comment: ok Tabla is your custom class I thought TableLayout. You can call findViewWithTag on any View. So you can create method in Tabla class that uses TableLayout to findViewWithTag

Comment: I did: **public String returnText(String tag){
        EditText texto = (EditText)tabla.findViewWithTag(tag);

        return texto.getText().toString();
    }** and I call it **@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String texto = tabla.returnText("EditText1");
                Log.v("GETTEXT",texto);
            }**

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know how to do a getText from the EditText

I'm not sure what you don't understand but EditTexts do in fact have a `getText()` method. It returns a `Editable` and to get the string from that you just need to call `toString()` on that.

Comment: Yes I know but the EditText doesnt exist until the application starts because they are created in the Tabla.java not in the layout so i cant call them with getText() in a normal way.

Comment: why not? what's the difference?

Comment: In the java class they are called "texto" **EditText texto = new EditText(actividad);** but how i do a getText from nivel1.java? I cant do texto.getText()

Comment: i dont know the android studio says to me "Cannot resolve symbol texto"          if (id == R.id.resolvertop) {
            texto.getText();
            return true;
        }

Comment: The problem is that texto only exists in the loop where you define it. If you save each of them at class level instead for example you can access them, just like when you define views that you get from layout file

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some way of accessing the EditText object. I would recommend a method in your Tabla.class. Something like this:

```
public class Tabla {

    public TextView getViewAt(int row, int column) {
        return (TextView) filas.get(row).getChildAt(column);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to hold all `EditText` in an array just like other data.

Do

`EditText[][] ets = new EditText[9][9];`

in you member field and assign one by one inside your loop.

I can't understand your language so I'll just write a simple example.

```
for(int y=0; y<9; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x<9; x++) {
        EditText et = ets[y][x] = new EditText(...);
        // initialize, attatch listeners to et
    }
}
```

**Edit**

So you have **some** `EditText`s and **some** `TextViews`.

To hold them all in a same array, instead of `EditText`, hold them as `TextView` as `TextView` is a super class of `EditText`.

So it will be like

```
TextView[][] tvs = new TextView[9][9];


// ...


for(int y=0; y<9; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x<9; x++) {
        if( fixed[y][x] ) { // check if the number of the cell is fixed.
            tvs[y][x] = new TextView(...);
            // Initialize tvs[y][x];
        } else {
            tvs[y][x] = new EditText(...);
            // initialize, attatch listeners to tvs[y][x];
        }
    }
}
```

Later, you can check `fixed[y][x]` to check if there is an `EditText` or `TextView` and if it is `EditText`, cast like `EditText et = (EditText) tvs[y][x];`

Or, check with `instance of` like

```
if(tvs[y][x] instanceof EditText) {
     EditText et = (EditText) tvs[y][x];
     // do something with et
}
```